# Execute shell command in new buffer without switching to it

Tags: vimscript, split

I want to execute a shell command in a new buffer from within Vimscript, but do not want to move the focus (cursor) out of the current active buffer.

Currently I'm using the following function:

```
function! s:ExecuteInShell(command, bang)
    " http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window
    let _ = a:bang != '' ? s:_ : a:command == '' ? '' : join(map(split(a:command), 'expand(v:val)'))
    if (_ != '')
        let s:_ = _
        let bufnr = bufnr('%')
        let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . _ . '$')
        silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'belowright new ' . fnameescape(_) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
        setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile wrap number
        silent! :%d
        let message = 'Execute ' . _ . '...'
        call append(0, message)
        echo message
        silent! 2d | resize 1 | redraw
        silent! execute 'silent! %!'. _
        silent! execute 'resize ' . line('$')
        silent! execute 'syntax on'
        silent! execute 'autocmd BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr . ') . ''wincmd w'''
        silent! execute 'autocmd BufEnter <buffer> execute ''resize '' .  line(''$'')'
        silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <CR> :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . _ . ''', '''')<CR>'
        silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . _ . ''', '''')<CR>'
        silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>g :execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr . ') . ''wincmd w''<CR>'
        nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <C-W>_ :execute 'resize ' . line('$')<CR>
        silent! syntax on
    endif
endfunction
```

It works great but moves the focus to the newly created buffer. 
Can you please tell me how to modify it so the focus stays on the current buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
wincmd p
```

at the end of the function.

This is the equivalent of `Ctrl-w p` (go to previous window).

See `:h wincmd` (and the previous topic, some lines above).

Comment: great, thank you! can you please explain what exactly `wincmd p` does?

Comment: yw. I edited the answer to add an explanation.